# Which of these two APIs is the best to use REST or SOAP (for this specific architecture)?

Tags: database, api, rest, soap

Architecture :

- database on a central server which contains a complex hierarchical database structure.
- The clients should be able to insert data into tables through the API, The data would be inserted into multiple tables in the database at the same time, and not only into one table.
- The clients should be able to retrieve data by using a complex search query.
- The clients can upload/download files to the server which could have a size of multiple GBs

would SOAP be better for this job than REST ? can you please explain why ?

Comment: How would you recognize "better"? Faster, cheaper, easier, more cowbell?

Comment: i mean all of them, but I would prefer to know which of these two APIs would be "easier" to use to implement the mentioned points.

Comment: Why not XML-RPC or JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all the things you mention are equally achievable using either SOAP or REST, though perhaps a little easier with SOAP. Certainly it's easier to create client APIs for SOAP interfaces; client tooling support is significantly more advanced on the majority of languages.

*However*, you say that you're wanting to deal with multi-gigabyte upload and download. That's a crucial point as REST is able to handle that sort of thing far more easily. SOAP is almost always tooled in terms of DOM processing, and that means building full messages in memory; you don't ever want to do that with a multi-GB payload.

So go with REST. That's definitely your best option for achieving all your listed objectives.

Comment: @Frode: I suppose so, but the spec for that is large enough that implementing it without an existing support library would suck.